# how to delete data from two pivot table in same time in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, pivot-table, sql-delete, laravel-query-builder

i want to delete a project witch containe many 'Devis' and one Devis contain many 'Articals', so when i delete a project,the devis and its articals should deleted too

### Here is my code

Project Model :

```
class Project extends Model{

protected $table = 'project';
protected $primaryKey = 'idp';
protected $fillable = ['pname',];


public function devises()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Devis::class);
}}
```

---

Devis Model :

```
class Devis extends Model{

protected $table = 'Devis';
protected $primaryKey = 'idd';
protected $fillable = ['type', 'lot', 'prix_total_avant_tax', 'tax_perse', 'tax_amount', 'prix_total_apre_tax', 'notes',];


public function articals()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Artical::class)->withPivot('qte', 'total');
}
}
```

---

Artical Model :
class Artical extends Model{

```
protected $table = 'artical';
protected $primaryKey = 'ida';
protected $fillable = [ 'num_art' , 'designation', 'unite','prix_unit',];}
```

---

Project table :
[image]

---

Devis table :
[image]

---

devis_project table 'pivot table' :

[image]

---

artical_devis table 'pivot table' :

[image]

---

Thank You In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try that event of deleting the project make the magic.

In your Project Model add:

```
public static function boot() {
        
        parent::boot();

        // This method will be called before deleting $project 
        
        static::deleting(function($project) { 
             
            $project->devis()->delete();   
        
        });
    }
```

In your Devis Model add:

```
// This method will be called before deleting $devis 
public static function boot() {
        
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($devis) { 

             $devis->articals()->delete();
             
        });
    }
```

So you can simply

`$project->delete();`

Comment: hi mate, thank you for your help, when I submit the delete button the form action pass id of the project to the controller, where should I put that id in the code?

Comment: You don't have to do any special now, yours model are listening for the event delete, I suppose that in your controller have to pass the id to get the correct instance to delete.

Comment: yes i mean where should i put the id in the controller ?

Comment: Yes, the controller is where you are going to recieve id from view. Accept the answer if it helped to resolve your prob.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: To remove a one-to-many relationship record, use the detach method. The detach method will delete the appropriate record out of the intermediate table, it all depends how you made you migration and what relation type behavior you described there:

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Product $product)
{
    $project->devises()->detach();
    $project->devises()->delete();
    $project->delete();
    
    return redirect()
        ->route('project.index')
        ->withSuccess('Project deleted.');

}
```

Comment: there are two pivot table, we need two id to remove them, the firt is project idp and the second is devis_idd ,and i can pass only one id from view to controller